# Launching an exe file with it's GUI inside PHP on Windows

Tags: php, exe

I've got an Apache/PHP server running on Windows, and I'd like to execute an exe program with some lines of PHP.

I've tried many things that I found on this site and on others, but I can't find anything that works.

Some times there's no GUI, some times it's waiting for the program to close... Can't find anything.

Is there anyway to do it or is it strictly impossible?

Comment: What did you try, so people don't suggest what you've tried already.

Comment: Have you tried this solution from php.net? http://php.net/manual/pl/function.exec.php#86329

Comment: Seeing some code would be nice.

Comment: I've tried lot of things form the php documentation, including the one from the Exec function. I'm trying this for example : <?php 
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell"); 
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("mspaint.exe", 3, true); 
?>, and it's not working at all. The page is waiting, and Paint doesn't shows up.

Comment: See, there's a few issues at hand. You describe a server environment, servers are generally headless, or at least operate without direct interaction, a GUI implies interaction. Web servers are inherently multi-user, as such you could cause hundreds of applications to be open at the same time. Web servers run as a service level user, even if a user is logged on they might not be logged on as the correct user it is being run as.

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to make a client for a tv broadcasting server, and this client is just gonna be used by one client, and there's an exe I just wanna start and stop inside of my php program.

Comment: You wont be able to stop it. To stop an application the application must support it, generally because it is a service.

Comment: As alluded, PHP isn't designed to do this and I really think you'll struggle to do this through a scripting language like PHP anyway, given the points that doveyg mentions. The comments in this suggest you are looking for an interactive setup, so perhaps something like Remote Desktop would be a start? If you are running a non-interactive program, PHP can run such programs through exec but it will wait until it is done.

Comment: @Ocracoke, sounds to me Remote Desktop is unnecessary. Since remote interaction doesn't seem like a requirement, a shortcut on the desktop would work.

Comment: @doveyg The OP mentions running MS Paint in a previous comment, hence the suggestion. However, if it isn't a requirement, then, I would agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

To Launch the application try this;

```
<?PHP exec("c:\\\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe"); ?>
```

Then to close it;

```
<?PHP exec("taskkill /im notepad.exe"); ?>
```

The path depends on your system.

`exec()` just performs a command in command prompt. Its a massive security issue, but it works. Make sure you are running Apache/PHP as the logged on user.

Comment: My bad, forgot to escape the string.

Comment: Added a "close method".

Comment: I'm gonna check this out ;)

Comment: Ok, so it's working, but it's just starting the process (no gui). That's not a real problem, the problem is the page is loading until i manually quit the process...

Comment: What user are you logged in as? What user is the process running as?

Comment: Regarding the page loading until the process is quit; This is unavoidable most of PHP functions are `blocking`, unless you want to fork a script and terminate prematurely you are out of luck.